# Migrate HFM (Hyperion Financial Management) VB to Java new API

Tags: java, vb.net, finance, hyperion

I am working in a migration from an old VB HFM API to the new Java API for the Oracle Financial HFM framework Consolidation.

I have this piece of code in VB and I don't realize how is its equivalent:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim lValue As Long
    'The Hyperion application works internally with numerical representations
    'of dimension elements, e.g., a given entity might be represented as
    '"1162" in the database. The following lines get the internal values
    'of the various dimension elements, to be used in collecting information
    'from Hyperion. The scenario, year and period elements are assigned within
    'the "do" loops that follow, because they must get values for many
    'dimension elements.
    lValue = GetMemberID(HFMCONSTANTSLib.tagHFMDIMENSIONS.DIMENSIONVALUE, "<Entity Currency>")
End Sub

Dim oTreeInfo As HSVMETADATALib.IHsvTreeInfo

'Function that determines the internal Hyperion id of a dimension member.
Function GetMemberID(ByVal lDimID As Long, ByVal strMemLabel As String) As Long
    Dim oMetaData As HSVMETADATALib.HsvMetadata
    oMetaData = oSession.Metadata
    oTreeInfo = oMetaData.Dimension(lDimID)

    GetMemberID = oTreeInfo.GetItemID(strMemLabel)
End Function
```

For example, I couldn't get the analog in Java for get the Dimension member among other things.

I know in Java it must pass the `oracle.epm.fm.common.datatype.transport.SessionInfo` to get the `oracle.epm.fm.domainobject.metadata.MetadataOM` object enter code here and then I could get the Member but I don't know how it works.